# Stopping the SQL Server service instead of detaching database

Tags: sql-server, migration

I want to copy the transaction and log files for my SQL Server database and attach it to another SQL Server on another machine.

Instead of detaching the database, can I just stop the `SQLSERVER` service and copy files, or do I still have to detach and attach the database?

I am able to copy the file just by stopping the service, but I wanted to make sure it doesn't cause any problems.

I am using this method because I can't seem to use backup/restore

[image: restore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. It looks like the backup was corrupted or got damamged while moving from one server to the other and that's why I wasn't able to do BACK/RESTORE before.

I copied backup and all .mdf, .ndf, .ldf files over to the new server.

And ran following command:

```
USE [master]
GO

RESTORE DATABASE VDA FROM DISK = 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\VDA.bak' 
WITH CHECKSUM, 
MOVE 'VDA_Data1' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\VDA.mdf',
MOVE 'VDA_Data2' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\VDA_1.ndf',
MOVE 'VDA_Data3' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\VDA_2.ndf',
MOVE 'VDA_Data4' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\VDA_3.ndf',
MOVE 'VDA_Log1' TO 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\VDA_4.ldf',
RECOVERY, REPLACE, STATS = 10;
```

Results:

```
10 percent processed.
20 percent processed.
30 percent processed.
40 percent processed.
50 percent processed.
60 percent processed.
70 percent processed.
80 percent processed.
90 percent processed.
100 percent processed.
Processed 54808 pages for database 'VDA', file 'VDA_Data1' on file 1.
Processed 61104 pages for database 'VDA', file 'VDA_Data2' on file 1.
Processed 61440 pages for database 'VDA', file 'VDA_Data3' on file 1.
Processed 63312 pages for database 'VDA', file 'VDA_Data4' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'VDA', file 'VDA_Log1' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 240666 pages in 441.744 seconds (4.256 MB/sec).
```

Answer (score 5):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

Take a backup, copy the `.bak` file, and run a `RESTORE` command on the new server in a query window. You will probably need `WITH MOVE` - see the documentation:

[RESTORE Statements (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Don't use the terrible UI for this. Detach/attach or stopping the service is [the absolute ***worst*** possible way to make a copy of a database](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/).